# Autoshrink setting for UIButton in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

There is a setting for UILabel in storyboard that allows setting auto-shrink configurations, as shown below:

[image]

But I am unable to find the same for UIButton's textlabel. ***I am aware that I can set this programmatically but curious to know if there's a way to enable this setting for UIButton in Storyboard.***

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use User Defined Runtime Attributes to set this flag using the storyboard.

Set the following key path:

```
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth to true
```

[image: Adjust Font Size using Storyboard]

Answer (score 21):

**No**,  there is no option available in storyboard for set Button's textlabel auto-shrink ,

But you can set it programatically with **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** 
 as you are aware with it.

```
yourbutton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

Comment: you can set it via IBDesignable and IBInspectable

Comment: @techloverr he just want to know that is it possible from storyboard. He want direct option like Autoshrink in UILabel.

Comment: yes but we can show him another approach via just couple line of code instead of telling him NO in bold

Comment: @techloverr he already mention that he knows another approach with programatically.

Comment: @techloverr this not only via storyboard , you also need to do set some properties programatically.

Comment: @techloverr same here buddy. i also don't want to do. but can you say which option is better ? 2 line of code or full process with IBDesignable ?

Comment: via IBDesignable you can see the result directly without even running a code so it is better

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik let's clear I downvoted your answer because you suggested deprecated method

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
btn.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
btn.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5; // set whatever factor you want to set
```

If you want to set in storyboard try IBDesignable and IBInspectable

refer http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: so are you the downvoter for my answer, ok welcome bro, the question asked with out single code need to change , is this possible in UIButton

Comment: no hard feeling bro, it was deprecated so I did downvote

Comment: IBDesignable or IBInspectable we are assign the custom proerty , in here we add our own property whatever we need corret

Comment: with all due respect if we can set this property in the setter of our custom property

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 solution

```
class CustomButton : UIButton{
    @IBInspectable var adjustsTitleFontSizeToFitWidth: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = adjustsTitleFontSizeToFitWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var adjustsTitleFontSizeToFitWidth: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = adjustsTitleFontSizeToFitWidth
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.